# Why setting POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 does not work?

Tags: filesystem

From *APUE*:

> The `du` command on many BSD-derived systems reports the number of 1,024-byte blocks.
>   Solaris reports the number of 512-byte blocks. On Linux, the units reported depend on the
>   whether the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment is set. When it is set, the `du` command reports
>   1,024-byte block units; when it is not set, the command reports 512-byte block units.

First I run:

`ls -ls APUE.pdf`
`du -s APUE.pdf`

Got:

`18680 -rw-r--r-- 1 tianhe tianhe 19126025 2月  25 17:09 APUE.pdf`
`18680  APUE.pdf`

Which is `19126025 / 18680 = 1023.877141328`. So it's reporting as 1024-byte blocks.

Then I type: `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` in the current shell and run the above command again but still get the same.

What's wrong here?

Comment: a bit of info is missing here, have you tried adding it as an export in the .bashrc and then sourcing the .bashrc instead?

Comment: @tatsu no. Isn't `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` would be enough for the current shell?

Comment: yeah it should but doubting things will always work as intended usually allows you to uncover solutions you normally wouldn't ;) btw had you found this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605463/how-to-use-posixly-correct-in-grep

Comment: `env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` ?

Comment: @tatsu let me try:)

Comment: @tatsu Danm it works *_!

Comment: \o/ huzzah! please mark me as answer and upvote me! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be typing :

```
env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1
```

or

```
export POSIXLY_CORRECT=1
```

this is the correct syntaxe.

hope this helps :)

Comment: But I wonder why `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` doesn't work, I can't get `POSIXLY_CORRECT` value by `printenv | grep POSIXLY_CORRECT`.

Comment: I think this guy pretty much answers that : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38605674/4770754

Comment: No. I think it's not talking about the same thing. I just tried `export POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` and it works(`printenv` has `POSIXLY_CORRECT`). So by doing `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1`, it did not write the variable.

Comment: yeah I don't know if this is more or less recent but that seems to be the new syntax. I generally type `export` because it works. I experiment

Comment: Ya, thank you anyway. I would go search difference between adding `export` and not.

Comment: At least with bash, you can pass variable assignments to the command environment *without* exporting them explicitly, but they need to be all in the same line, like `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 ls -ls foo`. See the `ENVIRONMENT` section of `man bash`.

Comment: @steeldriver Oh, it seems that command `ls` and `du` reads configuration from global environment variables set by `export` or `env` instead of local environment variables. :)